# Windows 10 Laptop plugging two external screens on USB-C and HDMI

Tags: laptop, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Lenovo X1 Yoga with an HDMI port and a USB-C port, next to the USB-C charging port. The first time I tried to plug two external screens, it worked well, with the HDMI screen on the right, and the USB-C screen being a mirror of the screen on the laptop.

I now tried to plug them in again, and the USB-C plugged screen is not being recognized. Any ideas? Should I be (un)/plugging them in a specific order?

What I tried:
Plugging and unplugging the two cables in different order.
Plugging the USB-C cable into the USB-C charging socket.
Switching the external screen on/off after plugging.
Clicking on 'Detect' screens in Settings.

When it works, the screen is configured as shown below, where 1 and 2 are the laptop's screen and the USB-C plugged external screen, and 3 is the extension on the right of the main screen, with the HDMI-plugged external screen:

[image]

[image]